# Switching storage library in React Native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm switching from the [`AsyncStorage`](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) to the [`MMKV`](https://github.com/ammarahm-ed/react-native-mmkv-storage) storage library and I'd like to know the best way to remove the old AsyncStorage data from the devices of my users. I don't need to migrate any data.

I know I could just call `AsyncStorage.clear()`, but ideally I'd like to remove the library completely from my project. If I remove AsyncStorage, does all data created on the device by it get deleted as well? If not, is there another way to clear the old storage which I'm not aware of?

Appreciate your input!

Comment: You could call `AsyncStorage.clear()` firstly and after that, you can remove any trace of that library. If you just remove the library, the data stored in the local storage of the phone prior of its removal, will be kept there

Comment: I see, I was afraid I had to follow that approach. Wish I could have removed the library on the next update... Oh well. Thanks for your help!